# How to use lapply to count the number of missing values in dataset in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

I have a dataset in R titled NIS_data. I am trying to count the number of missing values for each variable using the following code:

```
attach(NIS_data)
lapply(colnames(NIS_data), function(var) {sum(is.na(var))})
```

My reasoning behind this code is that colnames(NIS_data) returns a vector; my function will then sum up the number of missing values for each variable. However, R returns a list of length 9 where each element in the list has a value of 1. I know that this is not correct (there is not 1 missing observation per variable). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use the data not the column names: `lapply(NIS_data, function(var) {sum(is.na(var))})`.  You could do the same thing more simply by `colSums(is.na(NIS_data))`.

Comment: Thank you! That works. Could you explain why I should be using the dataset and not the column names?

Comment: `lapply()` performs a function on each element passed to it.  In your attempt, it's checking if the column names themselves are `NA` rather than the data.  You could do `sapply(colnames(NIS_data), function(var) sum(is.na(NIS_data[var])))` which will give the same result by subsetting the data using the column names but there's no advantage to it in this situation.

Comment: Makes sense - thank you.

Comment: FYI, you don't have to use `lapply`. Just `sum(is.na(NIS_data))` would do.

Comment: Check out the `naniar` pacakge: http://naniar.njtierney.com/